# local vs non-local chsh

Tags: shell, amazon-ec2, aws

How do I get `chsh` in Amazon EC2 (Linux 2)?

```
$ chsh -s /bin/zsh
zsh: command not found: chsh
```

Here's what I see:

```
$ ls -ahl /usr/bin/ | grep chsh
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root     16K Jul 27 21:02 lchsh
```

Also, I [read online](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chsh.1.html) that:

> chsh supports non-local entries (kerberos, LDAP, etc.) if linked with libuser, otherwise use ypchsh, lchsh or any other implementation for non-local entries.

What does **local** vs **non-local** mean refer to here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Local** means accounts in `/etc/passwd`.

**Non-local** means accounts in *NIS*,*LDAP*, etc.

To install `chsh` run:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-10-10 ~]$ sudo yum install util-linux-user
```

Then `chsh` will work:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-10-10 ~]$ chsh
Changing shell for ec2-user.
New shell [/bin/bash]: ...
```

Hope that helps :)